# dotNet 4.0 Clipboard bug?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Try this:
1. Create an app in VS Express Edition 2010 (.NET 4.0).
2. Put these lines in the code wherever u like -

```
        string text = Clipboard.GetText();
        MessageBox.Show(text);
```

3. Copy some ANSI text (for simplicity) from notepad.
4. Run the app and see the result.

I see "Clipboard.GetText()" (without quotes) instead of actual data!

Can anyone confirm if this happens in Pro/Ultimate editions too?

Comment: I'd love to see the text in your notepad you copied.

Comment: @Nathan: Thanks much! Cool! Then this must be Microsoft's strategy to force ppl buy pro version =)

Comment: @Sebastian: I copied "Hello World" (without quotes, of course!) =D

Comment: @Nayan Seems unlikely :). If this is in fact a real bug perhaps you could do a screencast of it? Camtasia or something.

Comment: @Nathan: I'll post a screenshot. Video may not be possible anytime soon. But does it surprise you that VS2010 Express Edition may have a bug? It's possible. They are just normal human coders!

Comment: I'm not opposed to the idea of Visual Studio having a bug, however the bug you're describing would be in the core framework itself and not Visual Studio specifically.

Comment: @Nathan: I know that. But I was just being cautious :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead and post your results:

```
string text = Convert.ToString(Clipboard.GetData(System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.Text));
MessageBox.Show(text);
```

Comment: This (after typecasting) works. But then it must be a bug because all the functions that are public should work according to definition and documentation. Weird.